# Can't read superblock with veracrypt

Tags: 16.04, mount, encryption, veracrypt

I have a trouble when mounting a veracypt file container,saying

```
mount: /dev/mapper/veracrypt1: can't read superblock
```

How can I fix this error? Any help will be appreciated.

OS:Ubuntu 16.04

veracrypt 1.21

Comment: See https://github.com/veracrypt/VeraCrypt/issues/45

Comment: Thank you for your advice, bodhi.zazen.
But my VC file container was made not by command line but by gui.
The VC file container worked fine at firtst, but yesterday it went wrong suddenly.
I made a new container file using gui for testing  and it went well.

Comment: I am sorry you are having a problem. I suggest you file a bug report.

Comment: I resolved by myself, thanx!

Comment: You should post the solution.

Comment: @JacobSmith Can you write how you solved it? I have the same issue. Disk also created via GUI

Answer (score 4):

Connect your file container with VeraCrypt the usual way, except that you should uncheck the  option that mounts the volume. That is unlock the file container, but do not mount it. Then...

```
fdisk -l                       # This to know the name of the device.
sudo bash
fsck /dev/mapper/veracrypt1    # The device name should go here, e.g. /dev/mapper/veracrypt1
```

Here allow fsck to fix the volume for you. After a successful fix, dismount the (yet not even mounted) volume from VeraCrypt, then mount it again, but this time the usual way with actually mounting it at the specified path in the file system.

Comment: This answer worked flawlessly. Thank you. I was about to pull the drive and replace it.  You just saved me like a hundred bucks.